# Angularjs with pouchdb and CRUD

Tags: angularjs, couchdb, pouchdb

I am new to couchdb and pouchdb and looking for good resources to use angularjs with pouchdb.  I want to learn the CRUD operations to connect angularjs with pouchdb. I have not found any good resources to show how to do these operations.  Can we make this a good resource for people learning couchdb and pouchdb?

Comment: There's not much that would make it harder to use PouchDB with AngularJS. Of course you cannot rely on NG two-way data binding to replicate the CRUD, but besides this it should be pretty straight-forward. What kind of problems have you encountered?

Comment: I am trying to get the details of a profile on the array that I have in my client Profile controller.  I have a list of client names and I want to click on the name to show the details for that profile.   Right now, nothing is showing up on the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of the Angular libraries including

- ngPouch - https://github.com/jrhicks/ngPouch
- angular-pouchdb - https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb

There is a particularly nice article here:

- Classic TodoMVC walkthrough - http://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html
- Effeciently Managing UI State - http://pouchdb.com/2015/02/28/efficiently-managing-ui-state-in-pouchdb.html

Comment: Are these libraries any good?  I haven't been able to get theme to work with my project.

Comment: ngPouch was a little experiment of mine.  It worked fine, but I don't use it in production.